# Will documentation be available on non-English Stack Overflow sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-planned, documentation

I know that [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation) is only in beta now.

I want to know will it be available on Stack Overflow sites with different languages? (For example on [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/))

If it will, can anyone say a time horizon when this could happen? 1 year, maybe 3 years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We plan to bring it up on the international sites, but we've got a lot of work to do before that can happen. Right now, the system is in very early (but extremely functional) beta, and we have to allow for time for things to gel. That's .. going to be at least 3 - 5 months.

Once that happens, once we realize that we're unlikely to make any more major changes, new features, all bugs are pretty much fixed and stuff seems settled, we still need to localize it and there are *thousands* of strings that each site will need to tackle. There's also some work I hope we'll be able to get done on our behind-the-scenes translation process in order to ease this.

Once *that* is done, we can look at a schedule to roll it out gradually. I can't really commit to, or even guess at a time line for it at this point - it's too early. But yes, I very much want docs on the international sites.

The days of fighting through a language barrier to read documentation that isn't very helpful to begin with are coming to an end. :)

Comment: :) Glad to know that it's planned. Well if you are searching for another pair of hands that will help you to make this thing done it will be honor for me to join your team.

Comment: ... I think you mean 6 - 8 months, don't you? ;)